# Estimate the error of approximation of $ln⁡(1+x)$

Tags: calculus

Estimate the error of approximation

$ln⁡(1+x)  ≈x-x^2/2+x^3/3-x^4/4$
For $|x|≤0.5.$

I use Taylor formula and got this

$r_5 (x)= f^5 (x_0)/(5!) *(x^5)$

what do I do next to get the actual number.

Comment: I probably would not use the Lagrange form of the remainder. But if you want to, find an upper bound for $|f^{(5)}(x_0)|$ in the interval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, for the $n$'th order error term we have

$$ 
R_n(x)= (-1)^n \frac{1}{n!} \int_0^x (t-x)^n f^{(n+1)} (t) \; dt.
$$

Now, evaluate at $x=0.5$ and take $n=5$, i.e.  $|R_5(0.5)|$ is the error term.

Answer (score 0):

For an alternating series, the error is bounded by the first ignored term, which here is $+\frac {x^5}5$, so evaluate this at $x=0.5$